# Windows 10 IIS not reading application web.config

Tags: iis, windows-10, web-config, iis-10

On my local IIS I click on an application under the default website. When double clicking on connections strings or application settings, nothing is loaded in there. My coworker is setup the same and his IIS is reading the web.config correctly.

Any magical settings in IIS that would prevent it from reading the web.config in the root of the IIS application?

Comment: What is the full file path of your `web.config` file? And what is the folder your default web site points to? You need to edit the question to include a lot more information.

Comment: The description is too vague. IIS cannot read web.config, it may be caused by file path or permission. You need to provide more configuration information.